# Can I use an environment variable in Obfuscar config file?

Tags: obfuscar

The obfuscar config file needs to specify "InPath" and "OutPath". Is it possible to use an environment variable? If yes, how?
The reason is that this config file is in SVN and then should be used by people having their projects locally in different locations where the environment variable points to.

e.g.

```
<Var name="InPath" value="%MYDEVPATH%\Project\bin\Release" />
```

instead of

```
<Var name="InPath" value="c:\foo\foo\foo\Project\bin\Release" />
```

regards,
Tobi

edited: changed $(MYDEVPATH) to %MYDEVPATH%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible yet. Obfuscar does not attempt to evaluate environment variables.

I can create a work item to track this request and let you know once it is implemented.

Updated:

Fixed in https://github.com/lextm/obfuscar/commit/97eaa12ac75b2246bba64dd74752caa635ef8f7a

Should be part of vNext.

Comment: Hi Lex Li, just a few minutes ago i posted an issue at obfuscar project at codeplex. I made the suggestion to insert two lines of code (**"inpath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(inpath);"** and outpath) in the Obfuscar.Settings constructor. That should do the job for variables like %MYPATH%\foo\bar. Cheers, Matmok; edit: [link to workitem](https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/workitem/20)